# Help identify a 8 SOP chip

Tags: identification

I need help identifying the following chip. Appreciate any help that I can get.

Here are the markings:

```
23BX010
3S6538
  1348
```

If anyone can identify the logo that would be good as well.

[image]

Comment: It's a serial SRAM chip of some sort. 1Mbit.

Comment: Just fyi - 1348 is the date code. 48th week of 2013.