# Help Identifying this chip (ATH342)

Tags: components, identification, surface-mount

Fairly simple, I have a small 8pin chip on a board, and I have no idea what its doing, and cant find any information about it online. There are no manufacturer logos on it, and the serial number doesnt seem to come up anywhere. All 4 pins on the left side are connected to ground, and its difficult to see what the pins on the right are connected to. It *may* be connected to an SPI bus (the component on the right is a microcontroller).

The board actually seems like it should be fairly simple (just a microcontroller, a radio unit, and a keypad with some LEDs), but then there are a load of components connected near the battery and I have no idea why. One of them is a Vreg to bring the voltage down to 3.3V, but the rest...
I feel like this chip possibly has something to do with it. The board is also supposed to be very low power.

If you cant see the image, the serial is:
ATH342
08CM  Y
W0853RC
[image]

Comment: I believe that's an SSOP-8 package.

Comment: 4 of the pins are obviously grounded, pin 8 is almost certainly power from the position of C3, it's probably an I2C memory EEPROM/Flask of some sort. Take a oscilloscope or logic analyzer and probe pins 5,6,7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an Atmel [AT24C08C](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-8787-seeprom-at24c04c-08c-datasheet.pdf) I2C-Compatible, (2-wire) Serial EEPROM, 8-Kbit (1024 x 8). The type is actually given by the second line via its

> Truncation Code ###: 08C

[image]

The first line is not really the type, but indicates the manufacturer (Atmel) and date of manufacture: the 42nd week of 2013.

Also, @ = Country of Assembly and AAA...A = Atmel Wafer Lot Number.

Much is owed to https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4526/identifying-an-unknown-chip-on-a-pcb which identified a similar chip.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm so used to being able to google everything, so it's a big shock when googling part numbers doesn't seem to give anything.

Comment: @BWalker: Memory chips can sometimes be a pain to decipher. [This one](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/193564/help-identify-a-8-sop-chip) is still not solved, for example.